# python django long polling waiting

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use Django with Rest Framework. I made a long polling view to return the latest update to other clients.

To wait for long polling, I used time.sleep(seconds) function. but this seems it works only for the client who made change. other clients seems stuck in somewhere.

Could you advice the right way to wait for long polling in Python Django ?

```
class ChangedItemsPollingView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]

    def get(self, request):
        request_received_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        ten_seconds_later = request_received_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
        
        while(datetime.datetime.now() < ten_seconds_later):
            changed_items = Asset.objects.filter(updated_at__gt=request_received_time)
            if(changed_items):
                tmpJson = djangoSerializers.serialize('json', changed_items)
                tmpObj = json.loads(tmpJson)
                return Response(tmpObj)
            time.sleep(3)
        
        return Response([])
```

Comment: Code was ok but Chrome browser acts in Cache mode when the same URLs are requested repeatedly. it returns cached value back without touching to server.

Answer (score -1):

In long polling you have API endpoint that returns:

- information that it still waits for results
- if results is available, it returns the result

You shouldn't do long running operations in the `get()` method. You should queue it and process in the background (for example with celery).

Example:

```py
class PollingView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        # ...
        if result.is_available():
            return Response(result.json())

        return Response({"status": "waiting"})
```

Comment: yes but long polling should wait instead of sending response. how could it pause the response.

Comment: you wait on the frontend side, not on the backend side

Comment: I thought waiting in frontend is not a long polling..?
I am referring to this article.
https://t.info/long-pollingjavascrip